Mother struggling to survive after the fall of the Soviet Union
This is a long shot and I try to provide as much information as possible, but most of it is conjectural.
Meta-information:

It was a movie (but I cannot rule out a made-for-TV movie).
It was probably from Eastern Europe, but maybe also from other European countries: possibly a collaboration of several countries. Maybe Hungary was involved, Russia not necessarily.
Time of production: In between the end of the Soviet Union and about the mid-1990's (I doubt, that it was from the late 90's)
I don't know which language it was in. I think that the quality was good for its time. Cast was all Caucasian.
I don't know the main protagonist and don't remember seeing her before or after (but she may be well-known in the country of origin). I had the impression, that she was between 30 and 45 years old (but she may have appeared older to me, since I was so young). Probably not much older, but perhaps younger. She had brown hair, if I remember correctly.

The story:

The protagonist is a Russian woman with a (small) child. I think it was only one and not yet in puberty. 
Husband / father of child was not there. I don't think, that he was dead or divorced from her. I'm sure he was a soldier. I think he was still in the military and no one knew, when he would come back. There were also hardly means to communicate.
So the little family was on its own in post-Soviet Russia. In order to survive, the mother worked as a prostitute - I think either along the Russian border or even in a neighbouring post-Soviet country - to earn money.
There is only one scene I remember and it's so vague, that it may confuse even more than help. It's just an image of the mother (and maybe her child) in a public place (all concrete, maybe the end of a bridge) and there were also soldiers and crates and lot of people.

Sorry, that's realy not much. But it was a long time ago. Also hard to find something, since Lilja 4-ever overshadows everything with these search words. The film was probably a bit obscure.
Edit
I exclude

Lilja 4-ever from 2002: 100% sure about that.
Intergirl (Interdevochka) from 1989: A famous movie, but the plot seems to be completely different (the role of prostitution, the protagonist, taking place in Sweden etc.), too old.


I wanna say it's Lilya 4-Ever, but too many details don't match.

No, it's definitely not Lilja 4-ever.
